# GKE Auto cluster creation failing with DNS error

Tags: google-cloud-platform, dns, google-kubernetes-engine

GKE Cluster creation is failing with below error

```
`DNS API error: Failed creating DNS Managed Zone with name "gke-gke-webapp-poc-a769c313-dns", setClusterHash - false, error - googleapi: Error 403: Forbidden, forbidden.
```

Below is the command used to create the cluster

```
 gcloud container --quiet --project network-poc-9e21 clusters create-auto gke-myapp-poc --region  europe-west1 --release-channel regular --enable-private-nodes --master-ipv4-cidr 192.168.16.128/28 --enable-master-authorized-networks  --network  projects/network-prd-26a2/global/networks/shared-vpc  --subnetwork  projects/training-ord-26a2/regions/europe-west1/subnetworks/nonfrc1918-dev-nodes  --cluster-secondary-range-name nonfrc1918-dev-pods --services-secondary-range-name nonfrc1918-dev-services
```

Any suggestion to resolve this issue ?

Answer (score 1):

Based on the error message 403:forbidden, this is related to a permission issue. Kindly double check the roles as it may be a factor. The operation to create a DNS Managed Zone requires a role like ‘roles/dns.admin’ to create DNS resources. Attached is a documentation regarding roles that might be helpful on your use case.[1]

[1] https://cloud.google.com/dns/docs/access-control#roles